# Ruby - $or is not working in mongo local server, but working in online server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

```
DdFbcrawlLinks.where(:$or => [{:feedtype => "news"},{:feedtype => "wall"}]).all
```

DdFbcrawlLinks is my model and it has the values. But unfortunately the abouve line is returning empty array

But the same code is working fine  in online server

Please help

Comment: Its a keyword in mongo database ($or)

Comment: ya ia m surprised, because the same cod was working fine and now i dont know what happend..

Comment: yes data is there. I restarted the server. but no effect

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using locally and what version remotely? Run `mongod --version`.  `$or` was added in 1.5.3. (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24or)

Comment: latest version db version v1.4.4, pdfile version 4.5

Answer (score 0):

In your specific query, using $in would be better

```
DdFbcrawlLinks.where(:feedtype.in=>["news","wall"]).all
```

More: http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html

Comment: But if we need it in different fields?

Comment: And in MM, `.in` is the default for an array query criteria, so the above is equivalent to `DdFbcrawlLinks.where(:feedtype => ["news","wall"]).all`